# What is the meaning and etymology of the phrase "T4"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology

I have often heard Orthodox Jewish kids use a phrase "t4". It usually means "just throwing this out there for attenton" but I am not exactly sure. I have finally seen this in-print in this [Mishpacha article](https://mishpacha.com/a-reason-to-party/):

> (My kids would call this a T4, like a flex that I got to chat with Rabbi YY, but if you know how accessible he makes himself to anyone and everyone — the harder the question and more perplexed the asker, the more eager he is — you know that this is a shvache [weak] T4.)

What is the exact meaning of this odd phrase, and where does it come from? (The closest I can think of is T9, the old cellphone text system, but that seems unrelated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero said in the comments, it is short for "Therefore, what?" It's a phrase that points out that the implications of a person's statement is a brag, even if what the person said isn't an explicit brag.
For example, if one were to say,

> Man, my arms are sore from lifting 200lb weights yesterday!

Saying "T4!" would potentially be an appropriate response, because the person is merely complaining about his sore arms, but the implication is a brag, because by saying "my arms are sore from lifting 200lb weights" one can ***therefore*** conclude that the individual is capable of lifting 200lb weights, and perhaps does so regularly since he said it in such a casual, backhanded way.

You can find more in [the Urban Dictionary's definition](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=T4).